# Using wordpress Api for wordpress features

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am building an external website for a client using the bootstrap 4 framework. and they have a Wordpress with all of their data linked,  music and videos, etc stored in it. The Wordpress acts as just a management system for their content. I will be building a separate webpage/site for them to present to their users that will allow users to sign up and subscribe for the mailing list and updates etc.... SO having to never use an API ever. I was wondering what do I need to place in the index.php file to call upon the wordpress api from https://wp.example.com. Does it need to go into the head section or right before the closing body tag?

I would like to use the WordPress Api to GET or echo the current user's avatar and username. to include inside the bootstrap header navbar.

```
<?php
       global $current_user;
       get_currentuserinfo();     
       echo get_avatar( $current_user->ID, 64 );
?>
        <?php global $current_user; wp_get_current_user(); ?>
    <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
     echo 'Welcome Back, ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n"; echo 'User display name: ' . $current_user->display_name . "\n"; } 
    else { wp_loginout(); } ?>
```

and finally last but not least I would like to use the wordpress api to check if a user is logged in/out to display/hide a bootstrap button the will contain an exclusive menu.  I'm pretty new to this but I think its something like this

```
<?php global 
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
// <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Menu</button> 

    } else {
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary">SignUp/Login</button>
    }
    ?>
```

BUt I Dont know exactly how to call or request, head or include or whatever it is that is required to use the api from the https://wp.example.com installation in the html or where to place it ie.  , , to make these functions work. Please Help

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity to use the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/).

Comment: @cabrerahector I would love to use this but having to never use API I dont know the first thing about how to execute this or make it work. Can you help?

Comment: What you're trying to do is what is known as [Headless WordPress](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/10/headless-wordpress-decoupled/). Basically, you'll need to use either AJAX (JS) or PHP's [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get data from WordPress via the REST API and use that info to change the way your website behaves. Since you seem pretty new to all this it'd be a good idea to learn how to interact with APIs in general. Here's a good starting point: [WordPress REST API Beginners Guide](https://www.toptal.com/wordpress/beginners-guide-wordpress-rest-api).

Answer (score 0):

Definitely follow [cabrerahector's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9131961/cabrerahector) advice and look at the documentation for the WordPress API...that is the best place to start.

To answer your question...the only reason to use the WP REST API is when you do not want to use WordPress for handling the front-end of your website.

So... you will not be using your 'Theme' folder except for index.php, functions.php and style.css.

You will also probably want to put your WordPress install in a sub-domain and run your front-end from the primary domain.

I put the following code in my theme's index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = 'http://admin.example.com/wp-admin/';</script>
```

check out this article [Using WordPress as a Headless CMS](https://www.sitepoint.com/wordpress-headless-cms/)

Also, the WP REST API is limited...I have had to add several custom endpoints because some data is not included out-of-the-box.

You can get 'user' data by using the following endpoint

```
GET /wp/v2/users/<id>
```

[REST API Handbook/users](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/)